Swiper.js: Second slide overlaps the first with the "fade" effect
I am trying to implement Swiper.js and the error I am getting is that the second carousel item is overlapping over the first one. The issue persists even when I use the fade effect.
I've tried adjusting the space between and setting it to 0, but it didn’t solve the issue. Also ensuring that the height of the swiper container and the images is correct.
I've tried different Swiper modules like EffectFade, Autoplay, and Pagination.
What might be causing the overlapping issue with the second carousel item? How can I ensure that the slides transition smoothly without overlapping? Is there any missing configuration or CSS that's causing this issue?
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { EffectFade, Navigation, Autoplay, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/effect-fade';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

import '../../../src/styles.css';
// import { useRef } from 'react';

const Hero = () => {
  const cakeData = [
    {
      image: "/images/Category/wedding.png",
      title: "Elegance in Every Layer",
      subtitle: "Wedding Cakes to Remember Forever",
      description:
        "Celebrate your love story with a cake that’s as beautiful and unique as your special day. Handcrafted with love, our wedding cakes are designed to impress."
    },    {
      image: "/images/Landing/BirthdayCake-removebg.png",
      title: "A Slice of Happiness",
      subtitle: "Custom Cakes for Birthday Magic",
      description:
        "Brighten someone’s birthday with a cake tailored to their favorite flavors and styles. From kids' parties to milestone celebrations, we’ve got you covered!"
    },]
  // const swiperRef = useRef(null);


  return (
    <div className="bg-[#FEF2F5] ">
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={30}
        effect={'fade'}
        navigation={false}
        autoplay={{
          delay: 3000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        // onSwiper={(swiper) => {
        //   swiperRef.current = swiper; // Store the Swiper instance
        // }}
        modules={[EffectFade, Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >

        {cakeData.map((landing, index) =>
          <SwiperSlide key={index}>

<div className="container flex flex-col-reverse gap-10 text-[#333333] items-center py-14 md:flex-row md:gap-32 md:pr-0">
              <div className="md:flex-1 ">
                <h1 className="font-semibold font- text-4xl text-[#A55668]  leading-loose md:text-5xl">{landing.title}</h1>
                <h2 className="py-4 font-semibold text-sm md:text-lg">
                  {landing?.subtitle}
                </h2>
                <p className="pb-8 text-sm font-poppins md:text-base">
                  {landing.description}            </p>
                <button className=" rounded-full bg-[#ED6A77] text-white p-2 px-8">Order Now</button>
              </div>
              <div className="md:flex-1">
                <img src={landing.image} className="lg:h-[80vh] object-cover" alt="" />
              </div>

            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        )}
        </Swiper>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Hero

#app { height: 100% }

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
 
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}


Please create a live example, we need to know all the code

To avoid the overlapping, per SwiperJS Docs for Fade Effect, you want to use the prop of fadeEffect and set the value of crossFade to true to achieve what you want so your slides do not overlap.


import { Swiper } from 'swiper/react';

<Swiper
  effect={`fade`}
  fadeEffect={{ crossFade: true }} // this
  ...
/>



